# как данные из цикла разбить по датам php

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из базы циклом вытаскиваю все данные, эти данные выводятся по диапозону дат. Как мне разбить данные на:
Дата
Данные с этой датой
вторая дата
Данные второй даты
Спасибо.

Comment: где дата, здесь время только. Корректней вопрос задавай и таблицей выведи а не картиной.

Answer (score 0):

в общем случае такой вывод строится на следующем принципе

```
 $current = null;
 // <ul>
 foreach($data as $v){

     if($current != $v->group_value){
          $current = $v->group_value;
          // </ul>
          // <ul>
     }
     // <li></li>

 }  
 // </ul>
```